# How to make a notification for a HTML app

Tags: html, ios, css, ipad, intel

I am making a HTML app using intel XDK.
I know it's not so common to make an app using HTML, but it simply is the only language together with CSS that I know.

I want my app to have a weekly notification, so that I don't need to update anything. I just want my app to say: "new info has arrived" every Monday.
Does anyone know if there is any code for this, or if this is even possible?
I am very noob at coding so I do not know many coding terms besides HTML/CSS.
(I make the app for IOS btw.)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with only html and css. Html, simply put, is just a markup language for tagging things like text and images so that the browser knows how to render them and so that css and javascript can interface with them. You will need to incorporate some javascript to do what you are proposing. For example, if you copy paste this code into the console in your browser and hit enter, it will make a popup appear with the date. `alert(new Date())` Such an action is simply not possible using only html and css. I made this little code snippet for you to simulate how you might go about checking what day it is, and alerting 'new info!' or 'no new info because today is not monday'. I admit I am not familiar with Intel XDK, but speaking to you question - you will need javascript in some form or fashion. At any rate, perhaps my answer will give you some ideas and point you in the right direction.

```
var dateNow = new Date()
var dayOfWeek = dateNow.getDay()

var week = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday']

if (dayOfWeek == 1) { //if dayOfWeek == 1 then today is monday
    alert('New info has arrived')
}else{ //if dayOfWeek is not 1 then today is not monday
    alert('Today is ', week[dayOfWeek], '. There are no updates available on ', week[dayOfWeek], 's.')
}
```

Comment: Anything after the // is a comment and is not code. It wont be read by javascript. It is there to help with understanding my logic.

Comment: Also, you can include the javascript directly in your .html file by wrapping it in <script type='text/javascript'> *paste javascript code in here* </script>

Comment: Thanks for the reply! You really help me out understanding what I am doing. I will try to experiment with this code and start learning javascript to also be able to understand code better.

Comment: No problem, man. Hook ya boi up with an up vote if it helped. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you CAN do it.

Check this website out: http://www.darianshimy.com/blog/2012/08/14/web-notifications-in-chrome-and-safari/

But basically it is using the Notifications api which works cross browser.

For example, `Notification.requestPermission()`would pop up the "od you allow this website to access notification, yes or no"

And then you could go ahead and create the notification when needed.

Full API is here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API/Using_the_Notifications_API